# No method found rails tutorial lesson 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently stuck at lesson 8 of the rails tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-logging_in

I get the error undefined method `logged_in?' Here is my code

Any help would be appreciated

```
module SessionsHelper


def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
end

def current_user
    @current_user = @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

# returns true if the user is logged in

def logged_in
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-  

turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track'    

=>    true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
 <header class = "navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
     <div class = "container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", home_path, id: "logo" %>
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li> <%= link_to "Home", home_path %> </li>
            <li> <%= link_to "About", about_path %> </li>
            <% if logged_in? %>
                <li> <%= link_to "Log Out", '#' %> </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>

    </div>
</header>

</div>
<div class = "container">

    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</div>
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `?` in your method name in `SessionsHelper`. You wanted to this:

```
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

You are getting this error:

```
undefined method `logged_in?'
```

because currently you don't have a method named `logged_in?`, but you only have a method named `logged_in`. So, you just have to change the method name to `logged_in?`. Then, it will find the method and will work fine.